# How mount volume vscode dev Containers

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-volume, vscode-remote

When I use the "Docker Docker" image from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/master/containers/docker-from-docker in VS Code and try to run an image of the docker using volume the following error is shown:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: / workspace.
```

devcontainer.json:

```
// Use this environment variable if you need to bind mount your local source code into a new container.
"remoteEnv": {
    "LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER": "${localWorkspaceFolder}"
},
```

Command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v ${LOCAL_WORKSPACE_FOLDER}:/workspace debian bash
```